# Which subject deals with questions about texture mapping in computer graphics?

Tags: function

When we do texture mapping in computer graphics,
we care about following questions:

- How are texture coordinates(also called UV coordinates) generated for a specific geometry?
- How can we measure the quality of generated texture coordinates? By "quality" I mean, for example, is some part of mapped texture stretched too much?
- How can we design a mapping with some desired quality?

My question is: which subject in mathematics deals with those questions?

Comment: While I see you've been referred here from math.SE, this is very borderline on-topic for SO. Are you essentially just looking for a definition of terms? Can you maybe make this question more concrete?

Comment: @deceze I think I am content with a definition of terms. And it would be much better if one gives some suggestions on readings and learning path for a graphics programmer. Maybe I can supply some background information to this question: it rises when I think about the texture mapping for procedural geometry. I want to learn the theoretical foundation behind this task.

Comment: Then this question seems all the more off topic, sorry to say. Perhaps http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ or http://blender.stackexchange.com/ can help you, but do make sure to familiarise yourself with their policies and on- and off topic criteria.